# Ajax POST Multiple Parameters to WCF

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I would like to know how and if it is possible to send more than one parameter to a WCF service using JQuery and AJAX.

Let me explain...

I need to send A name, a code and an email address to a WCF function and there process it. My POST AJAX function looks like this :

```
    function AddCustomer() {
    var CustomerData = {
        "CustomerName": CustomerName,
        "CustomerCode": CustomerCode,
        "CustomerEmail": CustomerEmail
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "URL/SERVICE/AddCustomer/" + CustomerCode,
        data: JSON.stringify(CustomerData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        processData: true,
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert("success..." + data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

By running the above function, I am able to pass ( or so it seems ) the Code as a parameter. When i try to add more parameters, I get ParserErrors.
I want to send the CustomerName, CustomerCode, CustomerEmail to a WCF SUB on the server. 
The WCF SUB's Implementation looks like ;

```
 <OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke(Method:="*", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="AddCustomer/{Code}")> _
    Sub AddCustomer(ByVal JSONCustomer As Customers, ByVal Code As String)
```

The SUB looks like :

```
       Public Sub AddCustomer(ByVal JSONCustomer As Customers, ByVal Code As String) Implements ISERVICE.AddCustomer

        Try

            Dim Cust As New Customers

                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("SERVICE", "YAY!", EventLogEntryType.Information)


        Catch ex As Exception

            ErrorMessage = ex.Message
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("SERVICE", ErrorMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Can anyone help me getting all the data passed correctly to my WCF Service?

Comment: it looks like your `JSONCustomer' is an object. Does it have the 'CustomerName', 'CustomerEmail' properties?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
var CustomerData = {
    "JSONCustomer" : {
          "Name": CustomerName,
          "Email": CustomerEmail
    },       
    "Code": CustomerCode     
};
```

Assuming `Name` and `Email` are properties of `Customers` class

Also, looks like your `UriTemplate` should be `UriTemplate:="AddCustomer/{Customer}/{Code}"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have managed to get a bit further now. The problem is now that myJQuery client complains and says "404 not found. " It doesn't make sense as the service works ( as I get GET responses perfectly )

Comment: I can't really help you without the updated code. Did you verify you don't have any typos in the URL?